# '{0}'.format() is faster than str() and '{}'.format() using IPython %timeit and otherwise using pure Python

Tags: python, cpython

So it's a CPython thing, not quite sure that it has same behaviour with other implementations.

But `'{0}'.format()` is faster than `str()` and `'{}'.format()`. I'm posting results from *Python 3.5.2*, but, I tried it with *Python 2.7.12* and the trend is the same.

```
%timeit q=['{0}'.format(i) for i in range(100, 100000, 100)]
%timeit q=[str(i) for i in range(100, 100000, 100)]
%timeit q=['{}'.format(i) for i in range(100, 100000, 100)]

1000 loops, best of 3: 231 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 298 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 434 µs per loop
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) on `object.__str__(self)`

> Called by `str(object)` and the built-in functions `format()` and `print()` to compute the “informal” or nicely printable string representation of an object.

So, `str()` and `format()` call same `object.__str__(self)` method, but where does that difference in speed come from?

**UPDATE**
as @StefanPochmann and @Leon noted in comments, they get different results. I tried to run it with `python -m timeit "..."` and, they are right, because the results are:

```
$ python3 -m timeit "['{0}'.format(i) for i in range(100, 100000, 100)]"
1000 loops, best of 3: 441 usec per loop

$ python3 -m timeit "[str(i) for i in range(100, 100000, 100)]"
1000 loops, best of 3: 297 usec per loop

$ python3 -m timeit "['{}'.format(i) for i in range(100, 100000, 100)]"
1000 loops, best of 3: 420 usec per loop
```

So it seems that IPython is doing something strange...

**NEW QUESTION**: What is preferred way to convert an object to `str` by speed?

Comment: To be faster, you could also try using `i.__str__()` directly. Though `str` is really the proper way. Is it not fast enough for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The IPython timing is just off for some reason (though, when tested with a longer format string in different cells, it behaved *slightly better*). Maybe executing in the same cells isn't right, don't really know.

Either way, `"{}"` is a bit faster than `"{pos}"` which is faster than `"{name}"` while they're all slower than `str`.

`str(val)` is the fastest way to transform an object to `str`; it directly calls the objects' `__str__`, if one exists, and returns the resulting string. Others, like `format`, (or `str.format`) include additional overhead due to an extra function call (to `format` itself); handling any arguments, parsing the format string and *then* invoking the `__str__` of their `args`.

For the `str.format` methods `"{}"` uses automatic numbering; from a small section in the [docs on the format syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

> Changed in version 3.1: The positional argument specifiers can be omitted, so `'{} {}'` is equivalent to `'{0} {1}'`.

that is, if you supply a string of the form:

```
"{}{}{}".format(1, 2, 3)
```

CPython *immediately* knows that this is equivalent to:

```
"{0}{1}{2}".format(1, 2, 3)
```

With a format string that contains numbers indicating positions; CPython can't assume a strictly increasing number (that starts from `0`) and must parse every single bracket in order to get it right, slowing things down a bit in the process:

```
"{1}{2}{0}".format(1, 2, 3)
```

That's why it also is not allowed to mix these two together:

```
"{1}{}{2}".format(1, 2, 3)
```

you'll get a nice `ValueError` back when you attempt to do so:

```
ValueError: cannot switch from automatic field numbering to manual field specification
```

it also grabs these [positionals with `PySequence_GetItem`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c30098c8c6014f3340a369a31df9c74bdbacc269/Objects/stringlib/unicode_format.h#L440) which I'm pretty sure is fast, at least, in comparison to `PyObject_GetItem` [see next].

For `"{name}"` values, CPython always has extra work to do due to the fact that we're dealing with keyword arguments rather than positional ones; this includes things like building the dictionary for the calls and generating way more `LOAD` byte-code instructions for loading `key`s and values. The keyword form of function calling always introduces some overhead. In addition, it seems that the grabbing actually uses [`PyObject_GetItem`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c30098c8c6014f3340a369a31df9c74bdbacc269/Objects/stringlib/unicode_format.h#L421) which incurs some extra overhead due to its generic nature.