# Including variables in strings in different ways

Tags: python, python-3.x

What are the respective advantages of the below syntaxes?

I don't really understand why to use one or the other.

```
# 1
print("The total is "+ str(totalBill))

# 2
print(f"The total is {totalBill}")

# 3
print("The total is {}.".format(totalBill))
```

Comment: The advantages are evident and subjective: which is the clearest?

Comment: https://pyformat.info/ and https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/1076533323961327616?s=20

Comment: While f-strings are the latest improvement, older `.format` method is compatible with a lot more Python versions if that matters.

Answer (score 3):

While all of them could achieve the same thing in python for printing this, the f-string formatting in the second process is the latest one introduced in python 3.6 - [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/). The first method is simply adding one string to another string and then printing the conjoined string. `str.format()` in the third process was introduced in Python 2.6. `str.format()` was an improvement done over the previous `%-formatting`. The new f-string formatting is again improved over `str.format()` method. For printing lots of parameters, the `str.format()` becomes quite verbose. Also f-string usage is faster compared to `str.format()` method as well as the old `%-formatting`. F-strings are evaluated at runtime rather than constant values. At run time, the expressions inside the curly braces of f-string are evaluated in their own scope and then put together in the returning string. Process #2 where F-string literals are used, is advised over `str.format()` method as well as the joining strings process.

Here is a comparison :

```
from timeit import timeit as t
t("""totalBill = 100
print("The total is "+str(totalBill))""", number=10000)
# 7.241250243259877 seconds

t("""totalBill = 100
print(f"Total bill is {totalBill})""", number=10000)
# 3.1151810346903517 seconds
```

Comment: @William: see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40714555/python-string-formatting-is-more-efficient-than-format-function) on performance of the different methods. Might be significant, depending on how many strings you format.