# combine input with apostrophe in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, whitespace, apostrophe

My code:

```
name=input('What is your name?')
print('So you call yourself \'',name,"' huh?")
```

My output

```
What is your name?lll
So you call yourself ' lll ' huh?
```

Need to get rid of the space between lll and apostrophes

Answer (score 1):

`f-Strings` are new and Improved Way to Format Strings in Python and you can use these to get your desired output like this:

```
print(f'So you call yourself "{name}" huh?')
print(f"So you call yourself '{name}' huh?")
```

Output:

```
So you call yourself "Raja Norhuda Adnan" huh?
So you call yourself 'Raja Norhuda Adnan' huh?
```

Comment: It does not answer the question. The question is about having quotes around the{name} part.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to make this:

First one using % operator

```
name = "Alex"

print('So you call yourself "%s" huh?' % name)
```

Second using format

```
name = "Alex"

print('So you call yourself "{}" huh?'.format(name))
print('So you call yourself "{name}" huh?'.format(name=name))
```

Using f-string (works only in Python 3.6)

```
name = "Alex"

print(f'So you call yourself "{name}" huh?')
```

In all 3 cases result will be the same.

You can even go further and do something like this

```
print('So you call yourself "#name#" huh?'.replace('#name#', name))
```

If you worried about performance you can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40714555/python-string-formatting-is-more-efficient-than-format-function)

Answer (score 0):

A trick is to mix quotes:

```
name = 'foo'
print(f"So you call yourself '{name}' huh?")
```

`"` around the complete string

`'` around the item