# Is it better to `join` or `format` strings?

Tags: python, concatenation

Which is faster - more efficient - more proper?

`join`

```py
string = "Hello"

concatenate = " ".join([string, "World"])

print(concatenate)
```

or

`format`

```py
string = "Hello"

concatenate = f"{string} World"

print(concatenate)
```

Comment: It’s mostly opinion, but I prefer the second in this case. Join seems more appropriate when you have a list to begin with, but here you are making a new list just to call join.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40714555/python-string-formatting-is-more-efficient-than-format-function

I would check this post out. It's might help you.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I would personally use `format` as well, but a downside to it is that it is only available for python 3.6 and above.

Comment: The F-string is far faster, but not appropriate when you don't know how many strings you'll be passing to `join`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use join() function to concatenate string with a separator. It’s useful when we have a sequence of strings, for example list or tuple of strings.
Let's say -

```
s1 = 'Hello'
s2 = 'World'

print('Concatenated String using join() =', "".join([s1, s2]))
Output:
Concatenated String using join() = HelloWorld

print('Concatenated String using join() and whitespaces =', " ".join([s1, s2]))
Output:
Concatenated String using join() and spaces = Hello World
```

.format function -
We can use string format() function for string concatenation and formatting too

```
s1 = 'Hello'
s2 = 'World'

s3 = f'{s1} {s2}'
print('String Concatenation using f-string =', s3)
String Concatenation using f-string = Hello World

name = 'Pankaj'
age = 34
d = Data(10)

print(f'{name} age is {age} and d={d}')
Pankaj age is 34 and d=Data[10]
```

Answer (score 0):

They can do different things and be used together.

In your simple example, format (or sprintf or Template versions) **is** simpler to read and more Pythonic.

But consider a document generator with a header line and content lines for each item in a `in_list`.

You

- create an empty `out_list = []`
- `format` a header and append it to out_list
- loop through each item in `in_list`, `format` and append to out_list
- `”\n”.join(out_list)` to get your whole document

(At this point Jinja2 might also be useful)

Why use Template ($name) or sprintf (%(name)s) rather than f-string?

- Python version
- multiple possible templates i.e.  `Hello $name` and `Bonjour $name`
- Templates are defined elsewhere, possibly in another function or in a file.
- For extra rabbit holes, the templates themselves could be generated
  by code.  Let’s say a system to dynamically display fields resulting
  from arbitrary sql queries.